# Javascript != not converting for null?

Tags: javascript, comparison, operators

I have the following idiom:

```
if(typeof prop != 'null') {
}
```

I was under the impression that if *prop* is `null`, the `!=` operator will convert the null object to the string *'null'* for comparison?

In the above case, when *prop* is null, the expression is evaluated as `true`. Why does this idiom work for undefined? Isn't undefined an object? Just as null is an object?

Comment: You are comparing against the string "null", not the `null` object, so it is `true` that `(null != 'null')`.

Comment: @Cory Larson - sure, I thought it might work more like `if("1" == 1) // true`

Comment: You get that behavior more with numbers and empty strings than anything. You should research "truthy" and "falsey" comparisons in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of a null object is still an "object". If you alert(typeof prop) you'll see it is an object.

You want to check for a null value.

```
if(prop == null) {
    alert(typeof prop);
}
```

Comment: Jason Dean - you're indeed right - it was the use of `typeof` that was causing me confusion.

Comment: Running `typeof(null)` returns _object_, whereas `typeof(undefined)` returns _undefined_.

Comment: makes sense to me.  An undefined reference cannot have a type, it is undefined. But an object with a null value is still an object.

Comment: @wulfgar.pro
the type of undefined is the string undefined.

typeof(undefined) != undefined // true
typeof(undefined) === "undefined" // true

Comment: Right, typeof returns a string that tells you what the type is. The typeof(object) is the string "object", the typeof(undefined) is the string "undefined". typeof always returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug or dom insperctor to see what typeof prop is

```
console.log(typeof prop);
```

and maybe you can try this too

```
if(prop != null) {

}
```

or

```
if(typeof prop != undefined) {
}
```

depends on what you are trying to do really/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to remove the quotations from 'null'